# Set Table/Topic order in Apache Kafka JDBC

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Have 2 topics, **source_topic.a** , **source_topic.b** .
**source_topic.a** have dependency with **source_topic.b** (eg. need to sink **source_topic.b** first). In order to note the sink process, need to sink data from **source_topic.b** first then sink from **source_topic.a**. Is there any way to set an order of topics / tables in source/sink configurations ?

Following are the configurations used and there are multiple tables and topics. The **timestamp** is used for the mode for updating a table each time it is polled. And timestamp.initial set value to a specific timestamp.

The Source Configuration

```
name=jdbc-mssql-prod-5
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver:
connection.user=
connection.password=
topic.prefix= source_topic.
mode=timestamp
table.whitelist=A,B,C
timestamp.column.name=ModifiedDateTime

connection.backoff.ms=60000
connection.attempts=300

validate.non.null= false
# enter timestamp in milliseconds 
timestamp.initial= 1604977200000
```

The Sink Configuration

```
name=mysql-sink-prod-5
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics= sink_topic_a, sink_topic_b
connection.url=jdbc:mysql:
connection.user=
connection.password=

insert.mode=upsert
delete.enabled=true
pk.mode=record_key


errors.log.enable= true
errors.log.include.messages=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the JDBC Sink connector doesn't support that kind of logic.

You're applying batch thinking to a streams world :) Consider: how would Kafka know that it had "finished" sinking `topic_a`? Streams are unbounded, so you'd end up having to say something like "*if you don't receive any more messages in a given time window then assume that you've finished sinking data from this topic and move onto the next one*".

You may be best doing the necessary join of the data within Kafka itself (e.g. with Kafka Streams or ksqlDB), and then writing the result back to a new Kafka topic which you then sink to your database.